# How to update an excel dynamically in java

Tags: java, excel

I am designing  stock market predictor wherein the user is supposed to update his database of historical indexes through the web. I want to just add the new data to the TOP of my excel file. not Bottom but on Top of my file. Now i know i can make a copy and modify that copy and the regular stuff. 
How to do i avoid this complicated steps and do in few steps instead? 
is it possible to do this without making a copy

Answer (score 2):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)'s `Sheet` objects have a `shiftRows` method you could use to do this. Here's an example from the [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html):

- [Shift rows up or down on a sheet](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ShiftRows)
- [shiftRows API documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#shiftRows%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Here's an answer with some sample code:

- [How to create new rows in apache poi 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651305/how-to-create-new-rows-in-apache-poi-3-6/3658253#3658253)

Answer (score 0):

Why not update a .csv (which is easier) and at the end after all updates are done, convert it to .xls